# How to add row number dynamically in tcpdf of symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf in symfony 1.4 to generate some pdf reports. Code fragment of myReport.php is:

```
$pdf->MultiCell($cell0Width, 0, $accountCount+1, 1, 'C', $paint, 0);

$pdf->MultiCell($cell5Width, 0, $bank['name'] , 1, 'L', $paint, 0);

$pdf->MultiCell($cell11Width, 0, $act['Branch'], 1, 'L', $paint, 0);
```

The problem is when the value of `$act['Branch']` doesn't fit in the cell, Serial number (which is the output of the first line) skips one count. For example, Serial number is 17 after 15. Serial number 16 is missing as `$act['Branch']` shows in two lines.

How can I solve it?

Comment: I have used strlen to get the max size(via some trial and error) of that cell like                            if(strlen($act['Branch'])>24)
   $accountCount--;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `strlen` to get the max size(via some trial and error) of that cell like

```
if (strlen($act['Branch']) > 24) { 
    $accountCount--;
}
```

Comment: Seems more like a workaround but if it works for you then it's ok :)

Comment: can't do it within 2 days(Stackoverflow restriction)